# Contribution Report Section Headers no longer list subtotal amounts

Tags: reports

Previously, if you used a section header on a contribution detail report, the section header would show the number of contributions and the subtotal of that section in parentheses. So for example, if you were using Financial Type as the section header, it would show "Financial Type Name (# of gifts, subtotal of gifts). Now it only lists the number if gifts and the NOT the subtotal. is this expected behavior? Anyone know why the change?

Using Civi5.3.1 under WordPress.

Comment: do you know which 'previously'? and have you tested with dmaster to see if it is still an issue?

Comment: I have now. Not still an issue on wpmaster. I guess I'm upgrading. Thanks for the reminder Pete.

Comment: can you accept the answer below to help close this off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you test one wpmaster or dmaster to see if it is still an issue and if it is not then upgrade your site to the latest release.